# Best way to check Optional's boolean value and throw exception if true

Tags: java, option-type

I have a nullable variable `id`, by which I can get a `Location` by `getLocationById` (again nullable).
What I want to do is `if(id!=null && (location == null || location.isDeprecated())) => throw exception`, otherwise do nothing.

Following is the way I can think of (other than get the boolean out first and then throw exception after an if statement). But it will throw exception when `id` is null, which is not what I want.

Wondering if there's a better way? (I'm using Java17)

```java
Optional.ofNullable(id).map(service::getLocationById)
      .filter(Predicate.not(Location::isDeprecated))
      .orElseThrow(()->new BadRequestException("Location is deprecated"))
```

---

EDIT1: I figured I could do following but would be great if any better ideas:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(id).map(service::getLocationById)
      .filter(Location::isDeprecated)
      .ifPresent(l->{ throw new BadRequestException("Location is deprecated");});
```

---

EDIT2: Having asked all this, I agree with what @Holger suggested in the comment by using the old good way:

```java
if(id != null) { 
  var loc = service.getLocationById(id); 
  if(loc != null && loc.isDeprecated()) 
    throw … 
}
```

Because

1. It's also quite clear and readable
2. My code is in a hot path, and the `Optional` way introduces overhead and extra heap allocation.

Comment: One thing you're missing perhaps: `"Location is deprecated"` shouldn't apply when `id == null`, right? Seems like a potential bug (unless you intentionally want to raise the exception when the id is null)

Comment: *What I want to do is if(location.isDeprecated()), then throw exception*. Your code also throws an exception if `id` or location is null. Is that your intention?

Comment: I do NOT want to throw exception when `id` is null. That's right there's a bug with my code. will update it

Comment: So the result of `getLocationById` is not otherwise needed? You’re only using the values for performing this one check? You probably want to use `if(Optional.ofNullable(id).map(service ::getLocationById) .filter(Location::isDeprecated) .isPresent()) throw new BadRequestException("Location is deprecated");`, so you don’t throw an exception from the inside of a function evaluated by an optional (and it’s the only variant supporting checked exceptions). But I would rather use a good old `if(id != null) { var loc = service.getLocationById(id); if(loc != null && loc.isDeprecated()) throw … }`

Comment: @Holger I’m not quite getting "so you don’t throw an exception from the inside of a function evaluated by an optional", could you elaborate why is this preferred please? Is it the `( l -> {...` that you're trying to get rid of?

Comment: First of all, as said, it’s the only way if the exception is a checked exception, as the `Consumer` passed to `ifPresent` is not allowed to throw checked exceptions. To be consistent, it’s preferable to use the same pattern even if the exception is an unchecked exception. It’s also easier when you want to construct a nontrivial exception as you’re not limited to use only (effectively) final variables. Further, the exception’s stack trace is simpler, as it doesn’t exhibit methods of `Optional` or your lambda expression. It’s not an important aspect, but the advantages add up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your style and the style of your colleagues.
The second behaves differently when location is null, so they are not the same. To make it behave similarly you'd have to tweak it like this:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(id).map(service::getLocationById)
  .or(()-> Optional.of(createLocationWithDeprecatedFlag()))
  .filter(Location::isDeprecated)
  .ifPresent(l->{ throw new BadRequestException("Location is deprecated");});
```

Not quite as nice. So in your case I would suggest to go with your first approach. It is readable and from my point of view good to understand.

Optionals are not a replacement for conditionals and should be used when they make sense and not to simply avoid conditionals at all cost. Your case could as well be a more or less simple if, but optional isn't too bad here.

Answer (score -1):

Use a try catch block. Makes things simple when you're dealing with possible exceptions like the one in your case.